# Duplicated records in p:dataTable with live scroll and sort

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I met this issue for a long time, but found nothing helps or workaround to get avoid this.
The `<p:dataTable>` was set as livescroll and sort enabled.
when scroll and sort happens several times, there will be duplicated records displayed.
eg: the total records were 150, there are 200 records displayed and 50 duplicated.
Does someone know, if this a known issue of PrimeFace or there was wrong usage of `<p:dataTable>`?

```
<p:dataTable var="enty" value="#{reportListBean.entities}" id="list"
             scrollRows="50" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true"
             scrollHeight="600"
             filteredValue="#{reportListBean.filteredEntities}"
             filterEvent="enter" widgetVar="reportList">

    <h:outputScript target="body" library="js" name="reportList.js" />
    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" onstart="synchronizeRowToggler();"
            listener="#{reportListBean.onRowToggle}" />
    <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{reportListBean.filterReportList}"
            onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()"
            oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()" />

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:4%" />
            <p:column headerText="xxx" style="width:11%" sortBy="userName" />
            <p:column headerText="xxx" style="width:15%" sortBy="name" />
            <p:column headerText="xxx" style="width:10%"
                      sortBy="description" />
            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:5%" />
            <p:column headerText="xxx" style="width:8%" />

            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:6%" />
            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:6%" />

            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:30%" />
            <p:column headerText="xx" style="width:7%" />
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column />
            <p:column filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="userName"
                      filterStyle="width:80px;" />
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:inputText value="#{reportListBean.listFilter.rptid}"
                                 onkeyup="filterReportList()" size="25"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:inputText value="#{reportListBean.listFilter.nameCh}"
                                 onkeyup="filterReportList()" style="width:75px"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column />
            <p:column filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="timesBrowsed"
                      filterStyle="width:65px;" />
            <p:column />
            <p:column />

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel id="dateFilter">
                        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{reportListBean.fromIsDate}"
                                               onLabel="曆" offLabel="距">
                            <p:ajax update="dateFilter"
                                    listener="#{reportListBean.fromIsDateChanged}" />
                        </p:selectBooleanButton>
                        <p:calendar value="#{reportListBean.listFilter.fromDate}"
                                    pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" navigator="true"
                                    onkeyup="filterReportList()" label="建立於日期時間"
                                    rendered="#{reportListBean.listFilter.fromIsDate}" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{reportListBean.fromIntervalStr}"
                                     onkeyup="filterReportList()" label="建立於起始區間"
                                     rendered="#{!reportListBean.listFilter.fromIsDate}">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([0-9]{0,6})$" />
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{reportListBean.toIsDate}"
                                               onLabel="曆" offLabel="距">
                            <p:ajax update="dateFilter"
                                    listener="#{reportListBean.toIsDateChanged}" />
                        </p:selectBooleanButton>
                        <p:calendar value="#{reportListBean.listFilter.toDate}"
                                    pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" navigator="true"
                                    onkeyup="filterReportList()" label="建立至日期時間"
                                    rendered="#{reportListBean.listFilter.toIsDate}" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{reportListBean.toIntervalStr}"
                                     onkeyup="filterReportList()" label="建立至終止區間"
                                     rendered="#{!reportListBean.listFilter.toIsDate}">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([0-9]{0,6})$" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column>
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.userName}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.name}" rendered="#{!enty.canBrowse}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
        <p:commandLink id="cL_Browse"
                       action="#{reportListBean.browseReport(enty)}"
                       rendered="#{enty.canBrowse}" onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()">
            <h:outputText value="#{enty.name}"
                          styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.description}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.pages}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>


    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.timesBrowsed}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.timesPrinted}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.timesDownloaded}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.createDateStr}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{enty.jobID}"
                      styleClass="ui-outputText-rptListCell" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:panelGrid style="width:100%">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column style="text-align:left;border-style: none;width:60%">
                        <h:outputText value="op" />
                        &#160;&#160;
                        <p:commandButton id="browse"
                                         action="#{reportListBean.browseReport(enty)}" value="開啟"
                                         rendered="#{enty.canBrowse}"
                                         onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" />
                        <p:commandButton id="print" value="pr"
                                         action="#{reportListBean.printReport(enty)}"
                                         rendered="#{enty.canPrint}" update="list"
                                         onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()"
                                         oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()" />
                        <p:commandButton id="downloadCopy" value="dw"
                                         actionListener="#{reportListBean.downloadReportCopy(enty)}"
                                         rendered="#{enty.canDownloadCopy}" ajax="false"
                                         onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{enty.downloadFile}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton id="download" value="dw"
                                         actionListener="#{reportListBean.downloadReport(enty)}"
                                         rendered="#{enty.canDownload}" ajax="false"
                                         onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{enty.downloadFile}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="border-style: none;">
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </f:facet>
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="border-style: none;">
                    <p:dataGrid var="aField" value="#{enty.fields}" columns="3"
                                styleClass="ui-datagrid-expand">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:panelGrid style="width:100%"
                                             styleClass="ui-panelgrid-nogrid">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column
                                            style="text-align:right;border-style:none;font-weight:bold;width:30%">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{aField.fieldName}" escape="false" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column
                                            style="text-align:left;border-style:none;font-style:italic;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{aField.fieldValue}" escape="false" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:dataGrid>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="border-style: none;">
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="noaccess" rendered="#{!enty.canComment}" />
                    </center>
                    <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height:300px"
                                   rendered="#{enty.canComment}">
                        <center>
                            <h:outputText value="nocomment"
                                          rendered="#{enty.conversationMap.entrySet().isEmpty()}" />
                        </center>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{enty.conversationMap.entrySet().toArray()}"
                                   var="conversationGroup">
                            <p:panel
                                header="第#{conversationGroup.key.pageIndex}頁[#{conversationGroup.key.coordX},#{conversationGroup.key.coordY}]"
                                styleClass="ui-panel-conversation">
                                <ui:repeat value="#{conversationGroup.value}"
                                           var="conversationEntry">
                                    <p:panelGrid style="width:100%"
                                                 styleClass="ui-panelgrid-nogrid">
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column style="border-style: none;">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{conversationEntry.userName}"
                                                              style="font-weight:bold" />
                                                <h:outputText
                                                    value="(#{enty.getShortDateString(conversationEntry.createDate)}):" />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column
                                                style="background-color:#E7E5DC;border-style: none;">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{conversationEntry.text}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                    </p:panelGrid>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </p:panel>
                            <p:spacer width="100%" height="5" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:scrollPanel>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public List<ReportListItem> getFilteredEntities() {
    return filteredEntities;
}

public void setFilteredEntities(List<ReportListItem> filteredEntities) {
    this.filteredEntities = filteredEntities;
}
```

Comment: all i can say is that PF4 scroll feather is absolutly not stable, in my case i was forced to rewrite all this component Server and client side

Comment: Unfortunately I have no ability to rewrite it, I was just using this framework recently.